# Retrieve Linkedin posts of type document with Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

Using Linkedin posts API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-12) and the version `202212`, I was previously able to retrieve posts documents (until april 2023)

Now, I don't receive the same data structure than before when I call this endpoint :

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts?q=author&author=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A9999999&start=0&count=100&projection=(paging,elements*(id,author,content(*,media(*,id)),adContext,commentary,visibility,createdAt,lastModifiedAt,publishedAt))`

Response received now, for instance :

```
{
    "paging": {
        "total": 16,
        "start": 0,
        "count": 100,
        "links": []
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "lastModifiedAt": 1683638910738,
            "visibility": "PUBLIC",
            "publishedAt": 1683638910738,
            "author": "urn:li:organization:9999999",
            "content": {
                "media": {
                    "id": "urn:li:document:D4E1FAQG22Pch2Nv65g",
                    "title": "test"
                }
            },
            "createdAt": 1683638910738,
            "id": "urn:li:ugcPost:706169341734422558848",
            "commentary": ""
        }
   --- more elements
```

I tried changing the `projection` parameter or even remove it when adding the newest version `202304`

Before, I received a response with an `identifier` and I was able to get data of documents associated to the post.

I also checked the changelog of the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/recent-changes?view=li-lms-2023-04) but it didn't helped me to understand how to solve this issue.